# Lenovo Flex 4 BSOD with new SSD

Tags: windows-10, ssd, bsod, sleep

I purchased a Crucial M4 128GB SSD (Model CT128M4SSD2) new from eBay for my Lenovo Flex 4-1580. The drive performs well, and otherwise meets its specifications, but I've run into an issue: Whenever I put my laptop to sleep with the SSD installed instead of the original 1TB HDD, there's about a 30% chance it'll BSOD upon wake-up. The blue screens seem to correspond with disk activity during the "going to sleep" process (IE: If I'm copying something or loading a web page, it seems as though the error is more likely to occur).

There are two separate errors which can occur, one is an `UNEXPECTED_STORE_EXCEPTION` and the other is a `CRITICAL_PROCESS_DIED`. I have no idea what causes one to appear aside from the other, but they both ONLY occur after waking from sleep with the new SSD installed. I've thought this may be a driver issue, but both Windows and Lenovo's update software are convinced there are no drivers which need fixing. Note that the installation of Windows on the SSD is a fresh install, not migrated.

The [unexpected store exception](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AjBj4z-ZvJiuga0jBeNPSQKHXQmiKA) and [critical process died](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AjBj4z-ZvJiuga0kglFCxLqxk9GfSA) memory dump files are available for viewing.